# Create a True/False Matrix by Comparing an nxm matrix and an nxc matrix (where c<=m)

Tags: r, matrix

I Have the following problem in R:

I have a matrix named "H" which is obtained by:

```
 v<-t(combn(x, 1))
 v<-cbind(v,matrix(0,nrow(v),2))
 y<-t(combn(x, 2))
 y<-cbind(y,matrix(0,nrow(y),1))
 z<-t(combn(x, 3)) 

 H<-rbind(v,y,z)
```

which would be the "nxc" matrix from title:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    2    0    0
 [3,]    3    0    0
 [4,]    4    0    0
 [5,]    5    0    0
 [6,]    6    0    0
 [7,]    7    0    0
 [8,]    8    0    0
 [9,]    9    0    0
[10,]   10    0    0
[11,]    1    2    0
[12,]    1    3    0
[13,]    1    4    0
```

Next I have an "nxm" matrix which is created by reapeating the first column (a sequence of 1:10 in this example) "n" times (based on H´s rows).

```
x = c(1:10)
c<-as.data.frame(t(x))
a<-as.data.frame(c[rep(seq_len(nrow(c)), each=nrow(H)),])
```

which would give:

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1.1    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1.2    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1.3    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1.4    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1.5    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1.6    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

Now, what I want to get is a data frame that compares these two and shows "TRUE" when a number from "H" is in one of the columns of "a" and "FALSE" when it is not. Just like this:

```
      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9     V10
1     TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
1.1   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
.
.
.  
1.n   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you comparing to come up with the true/false statements?/ Foe example, The last three true values in your output matrix, What did you compare to get them?? And also, The first true value in your output matrix and the False value below it, what did you compare to obtain them?? Just give a visualization so that one maybe able tosee what you are comparing

Comment: For the first row of the output that I want I compared:

The " 1    0    0 " of the first row of the H matrix with the first row of the "a" matrix which has  "1    2     3    4     5    6     7    8    9    10 ".

And after that obtaining a TRUE where the "1" is located on the "a" matrix. I hope this helps

Comment: That is a glipse. please if you can elaborate more twill be better. You have compared `row 1` to `row 1` what of the last row  of your output matrix? please just explain the first value which is false, the second value which is false and the last two values which are true. Thank you

Comment: If I could have known what is being compare to what I could have tried to solve it. But now it seems I asked a lot of questions: am sorry. you can try `mapply("==",a,H)`. of  which I cant tell what we are comparing.. If one could tell what is being compared then I guess your question will be solved

Comment: Onyambu, thanks for your reply.

The second value has on the second row of the H matrix a "2 0 0" as well as on the "a" matrix where the "2" appears on the second column of the second row and I want it somehow to give the output "False TRUE False False ... False".

The last row of the H matrix gives a "8 9 10", so in the same way as before I want it to compare it to the last row of the "a" matrix and show  "TRUE" on these columns i.e "False False .... TRUE TRUE TRUE". Tell me if this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  Well maybe I was a bit confused because the H matrix you presented above has  values `1,4,0` as the last row instead of `8,9,10` the way you have explained.  But I guess maybe you are comparing the each row of **H** to each row of **a** and then  where there is a **TRUE** we put it in the column which the true appeared.  Eg.  Taking the row 5 of H to be `10,2,3` we will compare this to row 5 of a eg as given above,  and put TRUE at column True at column 2,3 and 10. I believe I have gotten your problem.  I will answer you in a few hours time.  A little busy now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am back: hope this will help:

```
t(mapply("%in%",data.frame(t(a)),data.frame(t(H))))
```

The code above compares the values in the rows of `a` that are in the rows of `H` and give a `TRUE` when the value of `a` is in `H`. If this doesn't work Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps (b is the wanted data frame):

```
b <- data.frame()

for (j in 1:nrow(a)){
  common = intersect(H[j,],a[j,])
  for (i in a[j,])
  {
    if (i %in% common){
        b[j,i]<- T
    }
    else
    {
        b[j,i]<- F
    }
  }
}
```